# Resizing array in Java throws OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory

I have written a method to resize an array in Java:

```
public HUD resize(float factor){
    int[] array = new int[(int)Math.pow(pixels.length * factor, 2)];//Create new array
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x){
            array[(int)((x * 2) + (y * 2) * width * factor)] = pixels[x + y * width];
            array[(int)((x * 2 + 1) + (y * 2) * width * factor)] = pixels[x + y * width];
            array[(int)((x * 2) + (y * 2 + 1) * width * factor)] = pixels[x + y * width];
            array[(int)((x * 2 + 1) + (y * 2 + 1) * width * factor)] = pixels[x + y * width];
        }
    }
    pixels = array;
    width = (int)(width * factor);
    height = (int)(height * factor);
    return this;
}
```

This method is only called once and an `OutOfMemoryError` is given out whenever its called

Comment: Well cause you are probably trying to create a huge array on the second line

Comment: @DZDomi not even that big, I am starting at 12800 entries and go to 25600 entries

Comment: Did you mean to square the number? `12800^2 = 163840000`

Comment: @Bubletan yep I meant that. Well I understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the heap size of your application may prevent the `OutOfMemoryError`. [This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java) explains how to do this.